# Triggering a google apps script for all the users except administrators

Tags: google-apps-script, google-apps, google-apps-marketplace

How do i configure a google apps trigger for all the domain level users except administratos. Is there any global level configuration available ? or do i need to go individual users account and manually configure the same ?

Comment: You could have an object with the admin names, and when the script runs check if the current user is an admin, and if so, don't run the script.

Comment: Sandy , But how can i configure my script to run all the users.

Comment: Can you edit your question, and add some more info?  What are the steps the user takes?  Open the app, click a button?  What does the trigger do and when does it run?  Have you looked at any documentation, and what is the link?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not possible to have an Apps Script run for all users of a domain. Each user must run the code individually. If you wish to run a script for all users in a domain, consider using another platform / programming language and take advantage of service accounts.